# Were both Valmiki Ramamyana and Vyasa's Mahabharata contemporaneous accounts?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, vyasa, valmiki

I think Valmiki appears in Ramayana and Vyasa in Mahabharata.

Is it true that they recorded what they saw directly and were not retelling what they had heard?

Comment: Jnana drishti . Through that both were written.

Answer (score 2):

Valmiki and Vyasa were present.

Valmiki was given a boon by Brahma that he will know all the incidents in Ramayana and he can write an epic on it. [More details in this answer.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26504/19725)

As for Mahabharata, [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3550/19725) goes in more detail.